# Execute unfluff with python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to execute [unfluff](https://github.com/ageitgey/node-unfluff) inside a python script using subprocess, but the result is always empty. 
If I execute it from the shell, it goes ok. Here is an example:

From the unfluff documentation I can extract the contents of a webpage through:

```
curl -s 'http://observador.pt/2016/10/29/espanha-e-portugal-sao-unicos-paises-da-ue-sem-populismo-xenofobo-diz-antonio-costa' | unfluff
```

This results in a nice json with a good content extraction. 
Now, in python I'm using the following:

```
import subprocess

url = 'http://observador.pt/2016/10/29/espanha-e-portugal-sao-unicos-paises-da-ue-sem-populismo-xenofobo-diz-antonio-costa'

p = subprocess.Popen(['curl','-s',url,'|','unfluff'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

which results in an empty string. 
So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

By using `|` in your command you're implicitly invoking the OS shell.

So you have to enable `shell=True` to do that.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['curl','-s',url,'|','unfluff'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Note: since you have `Popen` you could do it in a much cleaner way by opening 2 `Popen` instances, for instance like this:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['curl','-s',url],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('unfluff',stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p2.communicate()[0])
```

(then you don't need the `shell=True` parameter, EDIT: you still need the `shell=True` parameter on the second `Popen` probably because `unfluff` is not really an executable, so needs the shell to start)

the rule is: if you want to be safe, always set `shell=True` but the command line then depends on the OS shell and it's less efficient. So if it works without it, it's better.

Comment: Thanks. That almost worked. I now get the json but with empty fields.

Comment: which solution have you tried ? first or second? can you add with `shell=True` to the second at `unfluff`?

Comment: Ok, it worked when added `shell=True` to the second `unfluff`. Thanks!